# How does one block direct browser access of client side include files in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In an angularjs application, the `index.html` page is served when a user types `mydomain.com` into their web browser.  But the page has client side include pages, including `index_firstinclude.html`.  But there is a hole in the app because any user (or webcrawling spider bot) can see unintended content if they type `mydomain.com/index_firstinclude.html` into their browser.  This could lead to automated links to the unintended include urls from search engines and other sites.  **How can I make sure that the user is NOT able to see the content of `index_firstinclude.html` if they type `mydomain.com/index_firstinclude.html` in their browser?**

Here is `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/my.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">

    <script src="js/lib/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myController.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="myController">  
<table width=100%>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
                    <div ng-include="'index_firstinclude.html'"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no way to do this effectively. Angular will need to fetch these (client-side) using that exact URL. Who cares if they get unintended content if they give bad input? As for crawlers, just tell them not to crawl those URL's. Not that they'd find them anyway since they don't process javascript.

Comment: You can lock down files with your web server but this would cause the index page not to be able to load these. a couple of things you could do is Move your files into a folder so the url is not likely to be hit or you could use template cache to cache the views in memory and then you dont need the static fiels anymore

Comment: Are you using gulp or grunt as a build tool?

Comment: @TimCodes I am not using either of those build tools.  It is in eclipse, and I am using eclipse maven to build a war from the app.

Comment: If you decide to go with the caching method. here is a pretty good article. https://thinkster.io/templatecache-tutorial. Also I put a plunk to gather a little while ago that demos this as well  http://plnkr.co/edit/DSeWLVNoV2Fe0SJI3Bwa?p=info

Comment: Gulp, grunt , webpack or something like that really helps out with building Angular apps there are alot of great plug in that help with problems like this .if you have time i would reccomend researching and using one in your build process

Answer (score 0):

In your code example you include the index_firstinclude.html into your main page, so it's content will be visible to the site visitors and those bots who process javascript sites.
You can disable loading any specified files for specific useragents by configuring your web server. 
Also, if there are pages with content for authorized users only, you could serve them with server-side authorization check.